# In Spark, can I configure different CPU / memory for each executor using Spark Stand Alone?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a heterogeneous cluster. For example, I have below machines:

- 1 core 1g
- 2 core 2g
- 3 core 3g
- 5 core 5g
- 5 core 5g

And my Spark cluster is in standalone mode.

The question is when I use `spark-submit` with default parameters, it will use my whole cluster resource. But when I enter the dashboard in the application, I can see that one executor with 5 cores but only use 1g memory.

If I configure `executor-memory 5g`, those nodes with less than 5g of memory will not start executor.

How can I configure Spark to support executors of different specifications in one application?

For example:

- executor1: 1core 1g
- executor2: 2core 2g
- ..etc

Comment: I have never seen anyone do this. All Workers were the same in a Cluster. AWS may be different with EMR.

Comment: was for YARN, not standalone

Comment: So the memory in Spark Executor must be fixed?

Comment: Actually, for YARN it is different, but for Stand Alone which I have myself you can do per Worker. https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_spark_configure.html

Comment: See new answer, my apologies, I forgot the Stand Alone aspect initially.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Stand Alone installation (along side YARN) on an experimental single Node machine.

If you have multiple Nodes, then indeed you *can* set the properties *per Node* / Worker as per https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cdh_ig_spark_configure.html from what I read for a Spark Stand Alone Cluster. I am not a YARN expert, I just ran stuff as per the setup in the past in Cluster mode, so I cannot comment on the YARN perspective, only commenting on Stand Alone.

But you *cannot* do what you allude to, by setting such things explicitly with the spark-submit, i.e. *per App*. That is a standard interface over all run-time resourcing / cluster environments. And indeed, Stand Alone gets all resources unless you restrict, aka greedy.